# Extend Idea Ultimate database plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

Is it posible to extend database plugin from ultimate version of idea (13.1)? I want add some functionality (button with appropriate action) to SQL Console editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the code, as database plugin is closed source. 
You can however try to develop your own plugin and create a new action in an appropriate place. I wouldn't know how to communicate with the database plugin itself though.

[image: New Action screenshot]